# Invalidate node cache so hook_node_view() runs on each node view

Tags: 8, caching

My module uses hook_node_view() to add some contents to the node view.

```
function example_node_view() {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && $node->bundle() == 'example') 

  // Insert file listing content part
    $contents = Class::getContents();
    $build['example'] = $contents;
}
```

Drupal 8 caches the node view by default and only calls hook_node_view() once after each cache rebuild. For this module to function, hook_node_view() should run every time the node is requested. So, I am looking for ways to invalidate node:nid cache tag.

NB:
- I am not looking for ways to disable the caching for a development.

```
public function getContents(){
  return [
    "#type" = 'table',
    "#header' = 'header',
     .....
  ];
```

Solved by adding the CacheDependency to hook_node_view() as indicated by @4k4

```
$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
$renderer->addCacheableDependency($build, $node->id());
```

Comment: Have you tried going to Configuration > Development > Performance? (I'm getting this off the top of my head for D7, it might be a little different for D8)

Comment: Where is `$content` coming from? Is this from the database or external? How often does this change?

Comment: @chris-happy, thanks, but I am not trying to clear chache, I want to invalidate the cache-tag for the node requested.

Comment: @4k4 $contents is created trough some Classes and has it's own caching.

Comment: @Bundio, I'm not sure, what exactly is in $contents. I've based my answer on files, but this works for all database content.

Comment: The code you've added solves the problem by disabling all caching of the node. The node id has no cache data and then the cache max-age is set to 0. This is probably not what you've intended to do. You need to use as second parameter the entity you add to the build array. The node is already set, so you don't need to add it again.

Comment: If you add other nodes, then you would need to add the cache dependencies from these nodes, so that the cache item from the node will contain multiple node tags. Use `$node`, not `$node-id()`.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. You can easily disable caching with a max-age = 0. But most likely, you don't want to disable caching. You want it to get invalidated when there is actually a change. The question you should be asking IMHO is how to get the correct cacheability metadata (cache tags + contexts) for the data you display to get the best possible cache hit rate while still having it invalidated when necessary. For that, we need to know what you're actually displaying, that code snippet doesn't help. You coul ask that in a new question

Comment: @4k4 & berdir, thanks! In my module hook_node_view() MUST run every time node/nid is called, like in D7. $contents is not a entity. It is a list of files. By design it chosen that this file-list is un-managed and can change without Drupal knowing it. The only way to know, is to run the class that will find-out if there is any changes in the list. It will use it's own caching for efficiency. That process is only triggered by hook_node_view(). So while I understand the process is selectively invalidating the cache-tag by setting cache-context, this solution seems to be the right one.

Comment: Module is [Filebrowser](https://drupal.org/project/filebrowser)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For new content added to `$build` you have also add the cache metadata.

Example if you add data from a file entity do this:

```
$renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
$renderer->addCacheableDependency($build, $file);
```

This adds the cache tag for the file and whenever this file is changed, the cache item of the node which contains information from the file gets invalidated.

If  the added `$content` is already a render array with cache metadata drupal will merge this. You can check, which cache tags are missing in `$content` and add them in the class that generates this data.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays

If what the comment in the code suggests you have a list of files, you can add the tag `'file_list'`. All entities invalidate the tag `[entity-type]_list` when creating, changing or deleting an entity.

Edit:

If you use the standard tools, that is building single entity displays with the view() method and list of entities with Views, then you don't need to take care of cache dependencies, because the render arrays these tools produce contain all necessary cache metadata.

Comment: I have included a sample function how $contents is created. Indeed it returns a render array. If I understand well I can add a tag to this array and associate it with the node view owning this custom content. But I don't understands how that works because getContents() will only run when hook_view() runs and that will only run when the node cache is invalidated.

Comment: You tag the node with all entities it contains. For example if you have a node with a author and a file field, then you have three tags, from the node itself, the author and the file(s). If any of them are changed, then the cached node is invalidated and will be rebuilt in the next request for the node. As long as all of the content of the node remains unchanged, there is no need to run the code again, because this would produce the same result as the cached version.