# How to create a redirection programmatically?

Tags: 8, redirection

I try to create a redirection 301 with the [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module. For example, I want to redirect an URL source to an internal URL through my custom module.

I want to create a redirection when I create a node. Import old content, create a new node and keep the old path.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: The [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) contains this functionality. Unless you have another use case but then I would need more information in order to help.

Comment: You can use `RedirectResponse` to achieve this. Refer the following link [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/138852](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/138852)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to create a redirection when i create a node. I import a old content in create a new node and i keep old path.

Comment: You should definitely add more information to your question. What have you tried so far? What is your exact problem? Why don't you mention the migration you mentioned in a comment to one of the answers?

Comment: You can use below code snippets to create programmatically URL redirect. 

// Create an object with the redirect parameters
$redirect = new stdClass();
redirect_object_prepare($redirect);
$redirect->source = 'old-url';
$redirect->source_options = array();
$redirect->redirect = 'node/5'; // New system path
$redirect->redirect_options = array();
$redirect->type = 'redirect';
$redirect->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
redirect_save($redirect);

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to store redirects in database use the module [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect). This module provides a user interface to add redirects. The redirects are stored in a content entity, which you can also create programmatically:

```
use Drupal\redirect\Entity\Redirect;

  Redirect::create([
    'redirect_source' => 'redirects/redirect1',
    'redirect_redirect' => 'internal:/node/1',
    'language' => 'und',
    'status_code' => '301',
  ])->save();
```

You can do this at the time you create nodes from imported data or in entity hooks when inserting, updating or deleting nodes.

Answer (score 7):

You can change your .htaccess by adding this code :

```
#custom redirects
RewriteRule ^old/URL/path$ http://example.com/new/path [R=301,L]
#end custom redirects
```

Or if you want do this in Drupal :

```
return new RedirectResponse(Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('route_name'));
```