# Automatically create redirect for a file when the file is renamed?

Tags: 8, files, redirection

When a file is renamed in the file upload widget and the other file is set to temporary, is there any mechanism in the background happening with the Redirect module to create a redirect from the old filepath to the new one that was renamed?

Example, foo.pdf in a file widget, I remove it and upload foo.pdf again. foo.pdf is now called foo_0.pdf - but links that linked to the old filename in the site still exist, therefore is it possible to get those redirected to this one?

edit: [linking to related dilemma](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648816#comment-12032560).

Answer (score 1):

Using hook_node_presave get the url of the old one (foo.pdf) and the new url of the new one (foo_0.pdf) and then create a new redirect [as shown by 4k4 here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227978/how-to-create-a-redirection-programmatically/228021#228021).

To get the orignal value (ex: title), I know in D7 you can with `$node->original->title` not sure if this still works on D8, have not yet tried it.

Also, since your url ends with .pdf I am not sure if this will work, but hopefully it will.

Answer (score 0):

This module works for me: https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_download

Media entity download seeks to solve a content management issue when dealing with files and media by linking to the media/{media_id}/download route, none of the above really matters. Linking content to media/{media_id}/download will always fetch and return the right file without worrying that its the incorrect one, or outdated, or a unique url (document_0.pdf).

Comment: Yeah - I wrote it after I encountered this problem.