# How do I redirect in a class sub-classing the EventSubscriber class?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I want to redirect to a specific URL in an `EventSubscriber` class instead of showing the *Page not found* page. I followed [Symfony2 redirect for event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916439/symfony2-redirect-for-event-listener/12917228) but the redirect goes to the home.

This is the code I am using.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class PageNotFound implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  public function pageNotFound(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $id = '1234';
    $scheme_and_http_host = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
    $url = Url::fromRoute('myroute', ['id' => $id])->toString(); // this url exist (checked)

    $response = new RedirectResponse($scheme_and_http_host . $url, Response::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    $event->setResponse($response);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['pageNotFound'];
    return $events;
  }
}
```

#### mymodule.services.yml

```
services:
  mymodule.page_not_found:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventListener\PageNotFound
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

How do I redirect users from an `EventSubscriber` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To catch a 404 exception you need to subscribe to a `KernelEvents::EXCEPTION` event. As there is already a base class for html exceptions you don't need to code this yourself. You can simply put the code in an `on404()` method of a class that extends [HttpExceptionSubscriberBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!EventSubscriber!HttpExceptionSubscriberBase.php/class/HttpExceptionSubscriberBase/8.2.x):

> Utility base class for exception subscribers.
>
> A subscriber may extend this class and implement getHandledFormats()
>   to indicate which request formats it will respond to. Then implement
>   an on*() method for any error code (HTTP response code) that should be
>   handled. For example, to handle 404 Not Found messages add a method:
>
> `public function on404(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {}`
>
> That method should then call $event->setResponse() to set the response
>   object for the exception. Alternatively, it may opt not to do so and
>   then other listeners will have the opportunity to handle the
>   exception.