# How do I redirect users to an external URL?

Tags: redirection, page-controller

I implemented a controller class in Drupal 8, which redirects to an external site.  If I use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse, I get this error.

> Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

Using \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse, I get this error.

> The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early.
>   Returned object class: \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse

What should I do?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/2638686 and the related issues, you need to properly deal with cacheablity metadata, we can't help without seeing your specific code

Answer (score 4):

Define a controller and redirect to external URL.

Use `TrustedRedirectResponse` class in case you know that you want to redirect to an external URL. Example below:

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase; 
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse; 
class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

  public function example() {
    return new TrustedRedirectResponse('https://google.com');  
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP stated there was an error when using TrustedRedirectResponse, which was exactly what happened to me. Their solution below of using SecuredRedirectResponse worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**With a route name on a Controller:**

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;
class MyControllerClass extends ControllerBase {

  public function foo() {
    //...
    return $this->redirect('user.page');
  }
}
```

With a absolute url:

```
return new RedirectResponse('https://google.com');
```

Comment: It did not help for me. At last, I created a class which extends \Drupal\Component\HttpFoundation\SecuredRedirectResponse. It is required to implement isSafe($url) method to do so. In my case, this is sufficient. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Extended SecuredRedirectResponse did it for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively implement `hook_redirect_response_alter()` (as per [#2909182](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2909182) patch).

Here is the example from `redirect_test.module`:

```
use Drupal\redirect\Entity\Redirect;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

/**
 * Implements hook_redirect_response_alter().
 */
function redirect_test_redirect_response_alter(RedirectResponse $response, Redirect $redirect) {
  $path = 'test/redirect/2/successful';
  $replace = 'test/redirect/other';
  if ($redirect->getRedirect()['uri'] == "internal:/" . $path) {
    $response->setTargetUrl(str_replace($path, $replace, $redirect->getRedirectUrl()->setAbsolute()->toString()));
  }
}
```