# Event subscriber to invalidate a cache

Tags: 8, caching, event-subscribers

I am invalidating a cache tag in `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest', 100];
  return $events;
}
```

```
public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  if ($this->request->cookies->has('myValue')) {
    $this->cacheTagsInvalidator->invalidateTags(['my_tag']);
  }
}
```

When I refresh the page the tag is invalidated but the changes are showing on the next refresh, to which event/hook/etc. do I need to subscribe me to see my changes in single refresh ?

**Edit 1:**
I have 'Internal Page Cache' module installed. If I uninstall it, the code above works fine.

**Edit 2:** Added the `if` condition.

Comment: You would need a middleware, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287393/how-to-get-the-uncached-version-of-request-headers. But what is in (...) that you need to do this?

Comment: (...) is a simple condition, my issue is that the code in `onRequest` function executes to late.

Comment: Yes, this is why you need a middleware, because the internal page cache is executed outside of DrupalKernel. But if this is only a simple condition there should be an easier solution, normally you don't invalidate cache tags like this.

Comment: I edit my question and added the condition. I need check if a value is in cookie, if is TRUE, I invalidate a tag for re-render a block.

Comment: The condition makes no sense because you have no way back for a response without cookie value. You need a cache context for the cookie and disable page caching for pages where the block is displayed.

Comment: The block displays in all pages :(

Comment: Ok, did you think about building the block in javascript or, if you need server content, lazy-loading the block via Ajax?

Comment: Finally i did it implementing a middleware :) Thank you @4k4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it implementing a middleware:

`mymodule/mymodule.services.yml`:

```
mymodule.http_middleware:
  class: Drupal\mymodule\StackMiddleware\BeforePageCache
  arguments:
    - '@cache_tags.invalidator'
  tags:
    - { name: http_middleware, priority: 280, responder: true }
```

`mymodule/src/StackMiddleware/BeforePageCache.php`

```
...
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function handle(Request $request, $type = self::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = TRUE) {
  if ($request->cookies->has('myValue')) {
    $this->cacheTagsInvalidator->invalidateTags(['my_tag']);
  }

  return $this->httpKernel->handle($request, $type, $catch);
}
...
```