# redirect /node?page=1 to main page

Tags: 8, redirection

- I have already indexed drupal-8 website's pages with pattern like - node?page=1; node?page=2 and so on
- I would like to redirect them to site's front page

Tried:

- I have tried with the redirect module but its not working

Answer (score 2):

One way is to redirect page using events subscriber.

**src/custom_module.services.yml**

```
services:

    custom_module.custom_redirect:
        class: Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\CustomRedirect
        tags:
          - {name: event_subscriber}
```

***src/EventSubscriber/CustomRedirect.php***

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Class to redirect.
 */
class CustomRedirect implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Check redirection.
   */
  public function Redirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $attr = $event->getRequest()->attributes;
    $route_name = $event->getRequest()->get('_route');
   //Check route name and attr
    if ($route_name == 'check route name') {
        $front = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString();
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($front));
      }

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events = [];
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['Redirection'];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>**mytheme.theme**</strike>

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) { // <-- your theme may already have one
  // redirect if URL has a "page" param.
  if (!empty(\Drupal::request()->query->get('page'))) {
    $front = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString();
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse($front);
    $response->send();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this from a preprocess hook, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287393/how-to-get-the-uncached-version-of-request-headers