# Redirect users to an external URL

Tags: 8, users, redirection

Is it possible to redirect users from a controller?

I tried using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
public function hello() {
  $query = $db->select('coop.oad','x');
  $query->fields('x', ['oad_url']);
  $query->condition('x.oad_soc', $column_name,'=');
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchField();

  return new TrustedRedirectResponse($result);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How we replace goto with http status in drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138697/how-we-replace-goto-with-http-status-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Thanks but not working for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$redirect = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url);
return $redirect->send();
```