# Why does RedirectResponse not work on production server?

Tags: 9

I have a very simple custom block/form that takes a user id and jumps to their profile page. The form submitForm has this:

```
$uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');
$path = '/user/' . $uid;
$response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromUserInput($path)->toString());
$response->send();
```

This works as expected on my local dev system and on our staging server. For some reason, it does not work on the production site (different server but same configuration as the staging server, afaik).

There are no errors. The page does do a page load but stays on the same page.

I have added a log point to capture the response object. It is identical on both the prod site and the staging site.

The only thing I have seen in the past which appears similar to this (a page load with no errors but simply fails to do anything) is from Apache mod_security. Hosting company assures me it is not mod_security.

Any thoughts on something which could cause this or how to further debug the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never send a response in custom Drupal code. You can add it to $form_state when submitting a form:

```
$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

### Why you can't send a response?

Answering the last comment. The Drupal kernel is stacked. Each layer returns a response for the request it receives. If one layer sends response headers prematurely, this will not stop the process of building the real response also sent to the client. It's unpredictable how a platform reacts to this unclear situation. In your dev environment the browser is directly connected to the web server and what you see is that it reacts on the first redirect headers received. But this can change in production ...

If you want to alter the response returned by Drupal then it's probably the best idea to use your own layer in form of a middleware. See this great answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/303653/47547

However, if you can use the Symfony/Drupal API, like in this case the Form API, there is no need for that. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/304037/47547

Comment: Still not sure why my sending the reponse worked everywhere except the production server; but setResponse does work. Thank you.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/304037/47547

Comment: Tried to clean up some other code using "the correct approach". Have a controller where i changed return value to this: return $this->redirect('node.add', ['node_type' => $node_type], ['query' => $query]); and it simply refreshes the page i am currently on. Adding ->send() to the end makes it redirect to the correct url. Hmm.

Comment: There are 48 hits when I check Drupal for `return $this->redirect()`, and none of them sends the response.

Comment: @liquidcms `git grep --fixed-strings '$this->redirect('` shows many lines similar to `return $this->redirect('search.view_' . $entity->id());` and some of them are in controller classes that extend `ControllerBase`, but none of them calls `send()` in the object returned from `redirect()`.

Comment: Perhaps something in my code overrides (all) controller responses and breaks them; but ->send() allows it to process before hitting that point? No idea and can't imagine how to debug. I single stepped after the return and didnt see anything besides core that was hit (but 100s of steps and didnt go through to end). Also, my change was incorrect above; i don't return the $this->redirect()->send() (i assume ->send() queues the redirect so return is not required). I upgraded from D9.5.3 to 9.5.11 - no change. setRedirect() in formSubmit certainly did work; juts doesn't work for controllers.

Comment: Perhaps i'll post another question specific to this as this was initially about a form submit (answered) and why different in 1 env than another (not answered; but i'll assume some php lib at a different version between the servers, or something like that). Thanks for the help.